# J4L ocr setup in linux

Tags: linux

i used CENTOS 6
How to setup j4l ocr environment in linux(CENTOS).
how to install laptonica library manually
how to install tessact-ocr 3.1 manually

please give the directory aslo where am i install above library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done setup of J4L OCR oncent os

1   Install Leptonica

2       Download leptonica-1.68.tar.gz  and extract it after that put it in directory  “/usr/include”

3       Go to Leptonica directory and execute following commands

```
     I   ./configure
     II  make
     III sudo make install
     IV  sudo ldconfig
```

4       Install tesseract Download tesseract-ocr-3.01.eng.tar.gz and extract it after that put it in directory “/usr/include”
also execute following command.

```
     I   ./configure
     II  make
     III sudo make install
     IV  sudo ldconfig
```

5   Download eng.traineddata.gz and extract it after that put it in directory “/usr/local/share/tessdata”

```
    The command line for running tesseract is:

    tesseract <image> <outputbasename> [-l lang] [configs]
```